# Making TypeClass Instance for List

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Before getting to my question, let me state my understanding (perhaps incorrect) that a List `[]` is a higher-kinded type:

```
ghci> :kind []
[] :: * -> *
```

I could be mistaken, but, a `[]` needs a type since it's a `List of some type 'T'`.

Now to my question.

```
class Foo a where
  bar :: String -> a
```

Then, I try to create a `Foo [String]`. My understanding is that the `a` in `Foo a` is `[String]`. So, I'd expect `bar` to return a `[String]`.

```
instance Foo [String] where
    bar []    = []
    bar (x:_) = [x]
```

However, I get the following compile-time error:

```
ghci> :l TypeClassExample.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( TypeClassExample.hs, interpreted )

TypeClassExample.hs:5:10:
    Illegal instance declaration for `Foo [String]'
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
       Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for `Foo [String]'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I'm hesitant to add this compile-time flag without understanding it.

What is its significance in this simple code?

Comment: You still have an error `bar (x:_) = [[x]]` must be in instance

Comment: could you say more? I think you're saying that I have an non-exhaustive match? But those 2 cases should match all cases, I think, no?

Comment: @Kevin_Meredith `x :: Char`, and `bar :: String -> [String]`, but `[x] :: String`, so `[[x]]::[String]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Haskell language definition is quite restrictive, and only allows list instances to be of the form

```
instance ... => Foo [a] where
```

where in the head `a` is exactly a type variable `a`, disallowing e.g. `[Int]` or `[String]`.

However, you can require GHC to ignore this restriction. Just add at th beginning of your file the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
```

Many, many modern Haskell programs make use of this. Arguably, in the next Haskell definition revision, this GHC feature should be integrated.